# Django can't find custom user model, yet it's listed in settings

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I'm using a custom user model with django 1.5, but when I try to do the initial syncdb or access shell I get the following error: `ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model tfe.CustomUser not installed`. However, it IS listed in the settings.py file, so I have no idea why this could be happening.

```
    #models.py CustomUser
   class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Username',
        max_length = 40,
        unique = True,
        db_index = True,
        )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email')
    nation_id = models.IntegerField()
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Use 'yyyy-mm-dd' format")
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    website = models.URLField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','nation_id',]

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'tfe.CustomUser'
```

Comment: `tfe` is your application name, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is my app name.

Comment: Have you added `tfe` to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble importing a model, use `manage.py shell` and try importing from there. It will show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should list your app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Maybe it reduces complexity if you don't build your own custom model, but use the django mechnism to [*extend* the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).